# Airplay Streaming Video without Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, airplay

So I am aware there are various alternatives to Apple TV for receiving Airplay Streams, such as XBMC, [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com) and [Reflector](http://www.reflectorapp.com).

These work to some degree but what I'd really like is a standalone solution, just some software that listens in the background until it receives the stream and then bounces into life. XBMC has too much extra fluff (media center features) and AirServer/Reflection require a license.

It seems the above solutions spawned by reverse engineering the Airplay protocol and I imagine Apple aren't too happy about this.

Comment: Why do you [insist on asking people to speak for Apple?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71143/airplay-airserver-reflection-etc-legalities) Please have a look at our [faq] where we attempt to lay out the line between asking an on-topic question and asking for opinion/discussion. Also, keep in mind that we are not the place for questions about developing software. Using software is completely on topic, but this will need editing to stand alone without the implication that you are looking for advice whether to develop something and know whether you will be in Apple's good graces.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was more on track...

Comment: It's better, but things that ask why Apple X get closed by the community in lots of cases. Why not edit out the developer parts and see if the rest is useful to people in general.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is [reported to charge hardware license fees for AirPlay](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-03-23/apple-is-said-to-weigh-expanding-airplay-for-streaming-video-on-devices.html) support, so I'm pretty certain that they won't let you develop your own for free.

I've had great experiences with AirServer - it generally works well and it is very actively developed.  The license is pretty inexpensive and it can be installed on several different computers with a single purchase.

Comment: Do you know where exactly I might find information about the license fees?

Comment: According to this story, the license for audio-only streaming is $4/per device: http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-03-23/apple-is-said-to-weigh-expanding-airplay-for-streaming-video-on-devices.html

Comment: The link you supplied is about hardware vendors and not software vendors. It's not clear that anyone has AirPlay software that's been licensed by Apple.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that there are no licensed Airplay software vendors.